# Problem with Print Booklet in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, print-production, paper-size

I'm trying to export a PostScript file of a book design in InDesign with pages arranged for a saddle-stitched book using the Print Booklet feature. The problem i'm having is this:
[image]

Print Booklet shows a warning saying that the booklet doesn't fir the current paper size. The preview shows the landscape design rotated to a portrait orientation.

The page origination in Document Setup and the design itself is correct:
[image]

[image]

Any ideas as to the cause of the problem?

Comment: What is set up in Print Settings?

Comment: I just changed the Print Settings preset back to default which solved the issue. Had checked this window before but as most of the options where greyed out i did not feel the problem was here. Anyway thanks for guiding me in the right direction!